# How to reindex data from one Elasticsearch cluster to another with elasticsearch-hadoop in Spark

Tags: scala, elasticsearch, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, elasticsearch-hadoop

I have two separated Elasticsearch clusters, I want to reindex the data from the first cluster to the second cluster, but I found that I can only setup one Elasticsearch cluster inside SparkContext configuration, such as:

```
var sparkConf : SparkConf = new SparkConf()
                     .setAppName("EsReIndex")
sparkConf.set("es.nodes", "node1.cluster1:9200")
```

So how can I move data between two Elasticsearch clusters with elastic search-hadoop in Spark inside of the same application ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to configure the node address inside the SparkConf for the matter.

When you use your DataFrameWriter with `elasticsearch` format, you can pass the node address as an option as followed :

```
val df = sqlContext.read
                  .format("elasticsearch")
                  .option("es.nodes", "node1.cluster1:9200")
                  .load("your_index/your_type")

df.write
    .option("es.nodes", "node2.cluster2:9200")
    .save("your_new_index/your_new_type")
```

This should work with spark 1.6.X and the corresponding elasticsearch-hadoop connector.